# WindowManagerGlobal java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Tags: android

I get a few reports of this exception every week and I have no idea what's causing it. Can anyone shed some light?

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.closeAll(WindowManagerGlobal.java:325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3590)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3756)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```